# Build array dynamically with JavaScript/Postman

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, postman-pre-request-script

Looking to create a JSON response body with JavaScript/Postman as a pre-request script with some dynamic variables. The issue I'm having is dynamically generating arrays inside the array. The data I'm receving is a CSV file so the value is like so `Value1|Value2` and I need to separate the values from the pipe separator and pushing them into their own category array

Using the CSV value from the above example the output should be like this:

```
{
"id": 1,
"store": 1,
"title": custom_title,
"url": custom_url,
"content": content,
"categories":[
    {
       "id":1,
       "name":"Value1",
       "type":"Type"
     },
     {
       "id":1,
       "name":"Value2",
       "type":"Type"
     },
    //add more if needed dynamically
]
}
```

I tried something like this

```
var catNum = "Blog|Healthy".split('|');
catNum.forEach((value, name) => bodyRequest.categories.push({ 
    "id": 1,
    "type": "Category",
    "name": value.toLowerCase(),
    "blog_category_path": value
}));
```

Trying to push the above into the categories array `"categories":[]`

Comment: And the actual problem is? -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) + [mcve]

Comment: The second argument of the `.forEach()` callback is not a "name"

Comment: Use `Array.map()` instead of `Array.forEach()`. And if you want to use `forEach`, use `forEach(([ value, name ]) =>` so that the value and name actually get spread correctly after splitting. Else use something like `value[ 0 ]` and `value[ 1 ]` to correctly extract the name and value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var catNum = "Blog|Healthy".split('|');
```

returns an array strings to catNum.

Do this rather

```
catNum.forEach(value => bodyRequest.categories.push({ 
    "id": 1,
    "type": "Category",
    "name": value.toLowerCase(),
    "blog_category_path": value
}));
```